# Groovy and GWT: Combining both paradigms

Tags: gwt, groovy

Is it possible to develop an application in groovy using GWT components?

Luis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use Groovy on the server-side and GWT for the UI, that is certainly possible. You can use Grails (a Groovy web framework on the server), and the [Grails GWT plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/gwt) to help you integrate GWT with this framework.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so, because the GWT compiler is basically a [Java to JavaScript *source*](http://java.dzone.com/news/understanding-gwt-compiler) compiler (it would be possible if the GWT compiler needed Java bytecode). You can use Groovy on the server side though.

Answer (score 4):

Right now you cant use Groovy on the client side. One big reason is that Groovy relies a lot on introspection, and this is not available on GWT.

Comment: It is not available out of the box but can be emulated using GWT generators. (Although it would increase the size of the resulting Javascript file.)

Answer (score 0):

I have also wondered this, as it would be very nice.  Vaadin essentially does this and you can use their plugin:   http://grails.org/plugin/vaadin

Doing it this model, though, it is compiling components into Javascript and delivering from the server.  But unlike GWT components, these are calling back to the server every time you touch the API (though of course with Vaadin you can use GWT components as well).